# Accumulate function in Vector (STL) giving negative sum

Tags: c++, vector, stl, accumulate

When i am coding the code below, i am getting a negative sum (-294967296).

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<numeric>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    vector<long long int> v={1000000000 , 1000000000 , 1000000000 , 1000000000};
    cout<<"Sum of all the elements are:"<<endl;
    cout<<accumulate(v.begin(),v.end(),0);
}
```

but when i am coding the code below i am getting a positive sum (2000000000)

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<numeric>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    vector<long long int> v={1000000000 , 1000000000};
    cout<<"Sum of all the elements are:"<<endl;
    cout<<accumulate(v.begin(),v.end(),0);
}
```

What might be the reason?

Comment: Overflow.  The literal `0` has type `int`, so your usage of `accumulate()` adds up all the `long long int` values by adding them to an `int`.   An `int` (typically) can represent a smaller range of values a `long long`, and overflowing one gives undefined behaviour.   Change the `0` to `0LL` to cause `accumulate()` to give a result of type `long long int`.

Answer (score 7):

`std::accumulate`: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/accumulate uses the type of the last parameter for the calculation.

You should use `accumulate(v.begin(),v.end(),0ll);`, the `ll` makes the `0` to an `long long`, then all calculations are done in `long long` and so it will not overflow `int`.

Example: https://ideone.com/QQCYIW

Comment: Really appriciate code worked, thank you very much, but i want to ask, what actually mean by "the ll makes the 0 to an long long"? how can 0 be long long?

Comment: Literals have a type, so `0` is an `int`, but `0ll` is a `long long int`.

Comment: I would recommend `L` so it doesn't look like `1`